# SQL Pricing Tiers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pricing lookup table in MySQL where I need to lookup the right pricing based on the transaction quantity.

Say for example, i have a pricing table `pricing`, looks like:

```
product    quantity    price
prod1      1           4
prod1      10          3
prod1      100         2
prod1      1000        1
prod2      1           0.4
...
```

And I have a table called `transaction` where contains the sales data:

```
product    sales 
prod1      144
prod2      2
...
```

How can I get the sales multiply by the right unit price based on the quantity. 
Something likes:

```
product    sales    quantity    unitPrice
prod1      144      100         2
prod2....
```

I tried to join two table on product but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: why don't you use simple join on product ? and why the output first row is (144, 100, 2) ? whts the logic ? is the result for prod1 is ((144,1, 4), (144, 10,3),(144,100,2)) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the price is using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select p.price 
        from pricing p
        where p.product = t.product and p.quantity >= t.quantity
        order by p.quantity
        limit 1
       ) as price
from transaction t;
```

A similar subquery can be used to get other information such as the pricing tier.

For performance, you want an index on `pricing(product, quantity)`.